# browser/demo01.sol:8:33: ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'return' function age() private view return (unit) ^----^

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
//properties functions request 
contract AttrFnDemo{
    uint private _age;
    string internal _name;
    int public _num;

    function age() private view return (unit)
    {
        return _age;
    }
    function age() internal return (string){
        return _name;
    }
    function age() private return (int){
        return _num;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So many basic errors:

- When stating the return-value type in the function declaration, you should be using `returns`, not `return`
- There is no such type `unit`; you probably meant `uint`
- You forgot to declare 2 out of 3 functions as `view`; while this will compile successfully, it will make your life harder when you call these functions from the off-chain
- You named all 3 functions `age`, when they are clearly meant to be named differently; in addition, this code will fail to compile, because you cannot override a function with another function which differs only in the return-value type